# GWT - including source files outside module's package hierarchy

Tags: gwt, build, build-process

I have a GWT project in eclipse with the following structure for the GWT module

```
com.foo.gwt -> Dashboard.gwt.xml
com.foo.gwt.client
com.foo.gwt.server
```

I have different packages `com.bar.baz1`, `com.bar.baz2`, etc. whose contents I want to include in client side code. All the files are GWT JAVA->JS conversion compatible.

The problem is that the <source> tag in Dashboard.gwt.xml, treats the path as relative to the directory of `Dashboard.gwt.xml`. So I cannot reference anything outside `com.foo.gwt` hierarchy.

So I created a new module `MyNewModule.gwt.xml` in `com.bar` and included `baz1` and `baz2` sub packages using relative paths in  tag. Finally I made Dashboard.gwt.xml to inherit the new module.

This works fine when I compile the Dashboard module but fails when I compile MyNewModule.
That's because some classes in MyNewModule reference classes of Dashboard module.

I tried inheriting Dashboard module in MyNewModule. This creates a circular reference, but GWT doesn't complain about it. Everything works but I am not comfortable with the circular reference. I don't need MyNewModule, all I need is a way to  include code from packages outside Dashboard module's hierarchy.

I am wondering why GWT does not allow absolute source paths.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to compile each module separately. When you compile your com.foo.gwt project, GWT compiler will look for all dependencies in your com.foo.gwt.xml file and will compile ALL *.java files both your com.foo and com.bar.baz.* (and other libraries) to javascript.

As you said, its correct to put MyNewModule.gwt.xml in the com.bar.baz project and "inherit" it in your DashBoard.gwt.xml file. The part you are missing is to make a .jar file with MyNewModule project and put in war/WEB-INF/lib folder (just gwt.xml file and compiled java classes).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. I have a build script which does not explicitly compile the new module, and everything works. It was when I installed Google Plugin for Eclipse that it started automatically compiling every module in the project which made me think that it is an essential process. I don't need the jar though as I don't plan to use the MyNewModule separately, it was created just because absolute source paths are not allowed.